# find the exact solution ref The finite element method using matlab by Kwon and Bang

Tags: matlab, eigenvalues

[image]

The results found are as under [image]

how do we find the exact solution ref The finite element method using matlab by Kwon and Bang.Page no 280-281 Example no 8.10.1.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about analytical solutions to a problem.

Comment: I'd like to keep this open. Analytic solutions are frequently important to validating computational techniques. Understanding said solutions may lead computational folks to better understand this whole process.

Comment: @BillBarth True, but as you write in your answer: We need more information to answer this question, so it'll likely get closed as "unclear what you're asking" soon after it's reopened. Unless you have an idea how to edit the question to make it relevant to both the OP and future visitors?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have Kwon and Bang's book, so I can't say what it says near by this table, but presumably the "exact" solution comes from 1-D or quasi-2-D beam theory. If you search around, you should be able to find either a reference on the internet or in Kwon and Bang's book near the description of this problem. Presumably if you refine this from 4 to many more elements, you will get closer to the "exact" solution given here.

FWIW, this is a bit of an odd problem description since a beam of unit length and 1 by 1 cross-section is a actually a cube. I usually think of beams as being long and slender. Beam theory tends to make the same assumption. It's possible that the "exact" solution is simply the eigenmodes of the Laplacian on the unit cube.

I think we need more information to help you.